# How is this bitwise AND operator masking the lower seven order bits of the number?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

I am reading *The C Programming Language* by Brian Kernigan and Dennis Ritchie. Here is what it says about the bitwise AND operator:

> The bitwise AND operator `&` is often used to mask off some set of bits, for example,
>
> ```
>     n = n & 0177
> ```
>
> sets to zero all but the low order 7 bits of `n`.

I don't quite see how it is masking the lower seven order bits of `n`. Please can somebody clarify?

Comment: `0177` is octal

Comment: Octal is archaic, today you would use `0x7f`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The number `0177` is an *octal* number representing the binary pattern below:

```
0000000001111111
```

When you `AND` it using the bitwise operation `&`, the result keeps the bits of the original only in the bits that are set to `1` in the "mask"; all other bits become zero. This is because "AND" follows this rule:

```
X & 0 -> 0 for any value of X
X & 1 -> X for any value of X
```

For example, if you `AND` `0177` and `0545454`, you get

```
0000000001111111 -- 0000177
0101010101010101 -- 0545454
----------------    -------
0000000001010101 -- 0000154
```

Answer (score 6):

In C an integer literal prefixed with `0` is an octal number so `0177` is an octal number.

Each octal digit (of value `0` to `7`) is represented with 3 bits  and `7` is the greatest value for each digit. So a value of `7` in octal means `3` bits set.

Answer (score 5):

Since `0177` is an octal literal and each octal number is `3` three bits you have, the following binary equivalents:

```
7  = 111
1  = 001
```

Which means `0177` is `001111111` in binary.

Answer (score 4):

It is already explained that the first '**0**' used for *octal representation* of a number in *ANSI C*. Actually, the number **0177** (octal) is same with **127** (in decimal), which is **128-1** and also can be represented as `2^7-1`, and `2^n-1` in binary representation means take n 1's and put all the 1's to the right.

0177 = 127 = 128-1

which is a **bitmask**;

000000000000000000000000**1111111**

You can check the code down below;

#### Demo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0177;   // octal representation of 127
    printf("Decimal:[%d] : Octal:[%o]\n", n, n, n);

    n = 127;        // decimal representation of 127
    printf("Decimal:[%d] : Octal:[%o]\n", n, n, n);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Decimal:[127] : Octal:[177]
Decimal:[127] : Octal:[177]
```

Answer (score 0):

0177 is an octal value each digit is represented by 3 bits form the value 000 to 111 so 0177 translates to 001111111 (i.e 001|111|111) which if you consider in 32 bit binary ( can be 64 bit too except the remainder of the digits are populated as per the MSB i.e sign bit in this case value 0) form is 0000000000000000000000001111111 and  and performing a bitwise with it for a given number, will output the lower 7 bits of the number turning of rest of the digits in the n-bit number to 0.

```
(since x&0 =0 & x&1=x e.g 0&0=0 ,1&0=0, 1&1=1 0&1=1)
```